# Find all horizontal, vertical, or slant asymptotes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have been instructed to find all the horizontal, vertical or slant asymptotes of the following function:

$$y = x^3-4x^2$$

I know there are no horizontal or vertical asymptotes, but I'm having a hard time understanding slant asymptotes. How do I figure out if there are any of those?

Comment: A polynomial of degree bigger than one has no slant asymptotes.

Answer (score 1):

The slant asymptote of a function (if it exists) is the part of your function with a polynomial of degree one. For example, the slant asymptote of $\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x-2}$ is $x+5$ because $$\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x-2} = x+5+ \frac{12}{x-2}$$ and clearly $x+5$ is the polynomial portion of $\frac{x^2+3x+2}{x-2}$ with degree one. Your function has no polynomial portion of degree one, so there is no slant asymptote.

Comment: You gave an example of a rational function with an oblique asymptote.  A rational function $f(x)$ has an oblique or slant asymptote $y = mx + b$ if $\lim_{x \to \infty} [f(x) - (mx + b)] \to 0$ or $\lim_{x \to -\infty} [f(x) - (mx + b)] = 0$. They occur when the degree of the numerator exceeds that of the denominator by $1$, as in your example.  It does not make sense to speak of an oblique or slant asymptote of a polynomial function.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig changed my word choice.